# How to remove \n from output screen while using sent_tokenize using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am using sentence tokenizer but how can i remove unwanted /n from the output

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import PyPDF2 as p2
pdf_file = open("Muhammad_CV.pdf", 'rb')
pdf_read = p2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
count = pdf_read.numPages

for i in range(count):
    page = pdf_read.getPage(i)
    text = page.extractText()                               #Extract text
    tokenized = sent_tokenize(text)                 #Token
    all_words = []
    for w in tokenized:
    all_words.append(w.lower())                  #Lower case
# ///////////////// Stop Words ///////////////////////////
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filtered = []
    for w in all_words:
        if w not in stop_words:
        filtered.append(w)
    print(filtered)
```

The output i get:

```
{'the specialization includes:\n \n\n \nintroduction\n \nto\n \ndata\n \nscience\n \n\n \nbig\n \ndata\n \n&\n \ncloud\n \ncomputing\n \n\n \ndata\n \nmining\n \n\n \nmachine\n \nlearn\ning'}
```

The desired output:

```
{'the specialization includes: introduction to data science big data cloud\n computing data mining machine learning'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 text = '''\n Apple has quietly  hired Dr. Rajiv B. Kumar, a pediatric endocrinologist \n. He will continue working at the hospital part time \n '''

 tokenized_sent_before_remove_n = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
 #op 
 ['\n Apple has quietly  hired Dr. Rajiv B. Kumar, a pediatric endocrinologist \n.',
'He will continue working at the hospital part time']


 tokenized_sent_after_remove_n = [x.replace('\n','') for x in tokenized_sent]
 #o/p
 [' Apple has quietly  hired Dr. Rajiv B. Kumar, a pediatric endocrinologist .',
 'He will continue working at the hospital part time']
```

Comment: Thanks. replace function is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the string `strip()` method to remove surrounding white space.

Here's an example ( also using comprehensions, because that's the pythonic way :) )

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import PyPDF2 as p2
pdf_file = open("Muhammad_CV.pdf", 'rb')
pdf_read = p2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
count = pdf_read.numPages

for i in range(count):
    page = pdf_read.getPage(i)
    text = page.extractText()
    tokenized = sent_tokenize(text)
    all_words = [w.strip().lower() for w in tokenized]
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filtered = [w for w in all_words if w not in stop_words]
    print(filtered)
```

EDIT: corrected `trim` to `strip` :)

Comment: @smassey trim is used for removing leading and trailing space, but according to Muhammad he want '\n' to be removed and not spaces

Comment: @Muhammad just edit above code as , all_words = [w.replace('\n','').lower() for w in tokenized]